# Convert char to 1-character null-terminated string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

Say I have a `char` like:

```
char a = 'a';
```

How can I convert it to something like this:

```
char* b = "a";
// b = {'a', '\0'};
```

(Technically 2 `char`s since it should be null terminated)

My use case is in a ternary expression, where I want to convert `'\0'` into `"\\0"` (`{ '\\', '0', \0' }`), but every other character will be a letter, which I want to keep the same.

```
letter == '\0' ? "\0" : letter;
```

This works, but produces an error about mismatched type. I also have other things that this may need to be used for.

Things I have tried:

```
letter == '\0' ? "\\0" : letter;
// error: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression [-Werror]

letter == '\0' ? "\\0" : { letter, '\0' };
//                       ^
// error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

letter == '\0' ? "\\0" : &letter;
// No error, but not null terminated.

letter == '\0' ? "\\0" : (char*) { letter, '\0' };
//                                 ^~~~~~
// error: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
// 
// ter == '\0' ? "\\0" : (char*) { letter, '\0' };
//                                         ^~~~
// error: excess elements in scalar initializer [-Werror]
// Seems to want to initialise a char* from just the first thing in the list

char string[2] = {letter, 0};
letter == '\0' ? "\\0" : string;
// Makes a string even if it is `'\0'` already. Also requires multiple statements.

char string[2];
letter == '\0' ? "\\0" : (string = {letter, 0});
//                                 ^
// error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

Comment: `char b[] = "a";`?

Comment: @Artyer  This letter == '\0' ? "\\0" : letter; does not make sense because the left operand has the type char, So how do ypu imagine this assignment letter = "\\0"? And why are there two slashes used?

Comment: So you want to create a one- *or* two-letter string depending in situation? Then why not simply create a tree-character array (initialized to `'\0'`) and set the first and possible second element suitably?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In this particular case, yes. But I run into many functions that take strings that I want to supply a character to, and I keep having to do `char name[2] = {character, 0};` and was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's not hardcoded

Answer (score 5):

The shortest

```
char c = 'a';
char s[2] = {c};  /* Will be 0-terminated implicitly */

puts(s);
```

prints:

```
a
```

---

And if it's just about being able to pass the character to `puts()` (or alike) you can even use a compound literal

```
puts((char[2]){c});
```

or

```
{
  puts((char[2]){c});
}
```

with the latter releasing the memory used by the compound literal immediately.

Both print

```
a
```

as well.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, but how is that implicitly null-terminated? I thought that uninitialized values were considered undefined behavior, not zero-filled.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Special case for array, when you initialize one or more elements, the remaining will be zero-initialized.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: If an initialiser is specified, the varibale is initialised as specified by the initialiser. If the initialiser only covers a part of the variable (as per my snippet) the rest is initialised as if the variable were declare `static` (or would be living in global scope).

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[2] = "\0";
str[0] = c;
```

and you are good to go.

Or of course, if this is a harcoded value, then you could do:

```
char str[2] = "a";
```

Comment: Just doing `char str[2] = "";` would be sufficient.

Comment: @alk you mean that instead of `char str[2] = "\0";`? BTW nice answer of yours, wonder why it's not accepted . . .

Comment: Yes, that is what I meint.